# How to put a percentage defined width div behind responsive image without overflow

Tags: html, css, sass

I have a container that contains (duh) 1 image and one div.
The image is a map with a horizontal transparent line.
I want The div to fill the image, in a responsive way, horizontally, from the right, to the left, according to a percentage defined in PHP.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="canada-wrapper">
    <div class="percentage" style="width:<?php the_field('percentage') ?>%;"></div>
    <img src="<?php the_field('canada_img'); ?>" alt="">
</div>
```

I tried this CSS: (I got it from an example of a div in FRONT of an image, which is the opposite of what I want, and I do not have a full ditdh div, unlike the example)

```
.canada-wrapper {
  img {
    margin:auto;
    position: relative;
  }
  .percentage {
    background-color: orange;
    height: 60em;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left:30%;
  }
}
```

It doesn't quiet work yet, it kinda does, but even if it did, it's not responsive at all because of the left, height and margin attributes on the div. This is the closest I could get.

I tried to look for similar questions but they never concern a percentage defined div, which changes everything.

Here is what I want it to look like: [image: Example of wanted result]

Comment: Is there any chance that you could please provide a link the the map so I can download it and properly play with this concept?

Comment: (without the red percentage line)

Comment: Just the image file or the website itself? I can send it to you in private, if it is possible to do !

Comment: Never mind, I just photoshopped it into what I wanted haha. I will get back on this after work today. :)

Comment: @Zze Thank you, there is no hurry! If it ends up not working, I will simply put the div under the map without the transparent line. Anyway, thank you so much for helping me out, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

I think that this is what you are asking for, however am willing to work with you to improve this if necessary. (No sass so I could make a code snippet.)

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.canada-wrapper img {
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.canada-wrapper .percentage {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="canada-wrapper">
  <div class="percentage" style="width: 50%;"></div>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" style="width: 100%">
</div>
```

The example is slightly awkward as there is no php changing the percentage, but you should see that the image now scales appropriately with the screen size. View the example in *Expanded / full screen* - stack overflow has a min-width in place and you can't see it in this small form.

Comment: It's going somewhere! The only problem is that the percentage div sticks to the right side of the browser [see image](http://i65.tinypic.com/dz586.jpg) . But, its percentage is according to its container at least, thank you so much for your reply!

Comment: @Antoine sorry, so where do you want the percentage div?

Comment: No it's okay! I want it inside the image, without being bigger than the image (no overflow) so that the div inside the image can show how far across Canada (the map) we are. Does that make sense?